# rotate 3d structure/image using jquery

Tags: html, 3d, html5-canvas

I have started working on a page website which uses javascript extensively. The main purpose of this site is to promote my customers products. This website will include one product 3d image. When user clicks and drag then it should rotate accordingly. Please see the link below. I need exactly the same kind of effect which is mentioned in following link

[I want same like this..](https://www.studio-shed.com/configure/)

Please give me some article or tutorial links as I searched but could not find any tutorials for this or any js..

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin and read its instructions I think this could be help full to you but you has to modify as per your product customization

See read me file and use example1.html it is best for your perpose

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Versatile-jQuery-Product-Image-Viewer-Plugin-SpriteSpin/examples/